# Can I leave typename unspecified in base class?

Tags: c++, templates, polymorphism

I am implementing polymorphic protocol handlers and in my base class I want to have a pure virtual function where the template function parameter is unspecified.  But my compiler is complaining.  I guess this cannot be done.  Anyone any suggestions on how to achieve this?  If at all possible?  Otherwise I will have to scrap the polymorphic idea.

Here is my code which gives me error C2976 'ProtoWrapper' : too few template arguments.  compiler=MSVC++2008.

```
#include "smartptrs.hpp"
#include <iostream>

class realproto {
public:
   const char* getName() const { return "realproto"; }
}; 

class real2ndproto {
public:
   const char* get2Name() const { return "real2ndproto"; }
}; 


template<typename T>
class ProtoWrapper : public ref_type {
public:
   ProtoWrapper(T* real) : m_msg(real) {}
   ~ProtoWrapper() { delete m_msg; }  //cannot have smart ptr on real_proto - so do this way

   T* getMsg() { return m_msg; }

private:
   T* m_msg;
};


class ProtocolDecoder 
{
public:
  virtual void Parse(ProtoWrapper<>* decoded_msg) = 0;  //problem line - compile error
};

class CSTA2Decoder  : public ProtocolDecoder
{
public:
   virtual void Parse(ProtoWrapper<realproto>* decoded_msg) {
      realproto* pr = decoded_msg->getMsg();
      std::cout << pr->getName() << std::endl;
   }
};


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
   {
      ref_ptr<ProtoWrapper <realproto> > msg2 = new ProtoWrapper<realproto>(new realproto);

      realproto* pr1 = msg2->getMsg();

      std::cout << "created new realproto\n";
   } 

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: why don't y@ou just declare both ProtocolDecoder and CSTA2Decoder also as templates?

Comment: Can you change the protocol classes themselves?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To pull this off, you need to turn `ProtocolDecoder` into a class template:

```
template <typename T>
class ProtocolDecoder 
{
public:
  virtual void Parse(ProtoWrapper<T>* decoded_msg) = 0;  //problem line - compile error
};

class CSTA2Decoder  : public ProtocolDecoder<realproto>
{
  //...
};
```

Comment: In this case, it is not easy to use ProtocolDecoder polymophically

Comment: @lzprgmr True. That is often the case: the principle of (dynamic) polymorphism is to hide static typing and replace it with dynamic descisions based on actual type. The principle of templates is to resolve behvaiour and typing statically. It is natural they tend to go against each other.

Answer (score 3):

Different template specializations are basically unrelated types. You cannot pass a template to a function, you need to pass a type (specialization) and there is no commonality between the different instantiations. In other cases you could use a template and let the compiler generate multiple overloads as you specialize the function, but you cannot have virtual template member functions.

The simplest advice would be to create a base class for your class template and pass that in. If the `Parse` function will create the object based on the decoded information then you will need to pass a reference to the pointer, not a pointer, so that the function can create the message. If on the other hand the object passed in to `Decode` determines how to interpret the message, then you will need to provide type information (either RTTI --i.e. at least a virtual function so that you can do `dynamic_cast`-- or manually craft your own).

On a side note, why can you not use smart pointers on `real_proto`?

Comment: real_proto and others are reall classes designed long ago which I can't change and do not have common functions nor inherit from some common base

Comment: >> The simplest advice would be to create a base class for your class template and pass that in.   ------- The problem is how to handle: T* getMsg()

Comment: @lzprgmr: That is why you need to have type information. You will need to cast to the appropriate type before using any specific functionality not defined in the base.

Comment: @user619818: You don't need to define a base for the `xxx_proto`, but for the `ProtoWrapper` types. That will enable passing `ProtoWrapperBase*`, and use type information internally (after the dynamic dispatch) to retrieve the specific `ProtoWrapper<T>` that you need to use.

Answer (score 0):

Why can't u simply declate the Decoder class as template like?

```
template<typename T>
class ProtocolDecoder 
{
public:
  virtual void Parse(ProtoWrapper<T>* decoded_msg) = 0;  //problem line - compile error
};
```

and when inhereting, provide the type

```
class CSTA2Decoder  : public ProtocolDecoder<your type>
{}
```